# How to accept multiple collection objects with the same name in a rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, simple-form-for

I have a rails form in which I would like to add a select dropdown. for each dropdown, the user can select a single value, but at the end I want to parse through each value entered in the different select boxes as a part of an array. How can I do this:

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
 <%= simple_form_for :or,
  url: path,
  method: :post,
  remote: true do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for "r_ids[]" do |ff| %>
    <% count.times do |c| %>
      <%= select(:or, :r_id, @r.collect { |r| [r.name, r.id] }) %>
      <br/>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit,
    class: 'btn btn-success btn-sm btn-update',
    data: { disable_with: 'Submitting...'}  %>
<% end %>
```

As you can see, I am using a loop to display the dropdown multiple times. for each of the dropdown, I would like to put the value in an array that allows me to obtain the values entered in each of the dropdown. How can I do this using either rails form helpers or simple form?

Comment: Can you give a high-level (from user perspective) of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have a form, which takes in a few fields, and then in the update action of the controller, I iterate through each array element and update the relevant record. The elements are supposed to be chosen from a dropdown list of user names. Hence I am using a loop to determine how many times the select dropdown should appear

Comment: This is how a high-level overview. Tell me what a user does here, so I can understand how to model code. You just told me how your code works.

Comment: A user comes in, selects some records he wants to modify, selects the options from the dropdowns and hits submit, causing the model to update with the params in this form. Each dropdown option here is used to update one row in the db. so basically I am doing a batch update, by allowing the user to choose how multiple rows should be updated

Comment: @MichalSzyndel does this help?

Comment: No. I'm trying to understand the types of objects or models in here and you talk about the db. There's a serious naming problem in your code, things should never be named `r_ids` because it just obfuscates the code. Sorry, but I see no way I can help unless you explain clearly what is going on in your code without using words row, model, params, and db.